# sklearn fit_transform and transform behaviour

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Puzzled by that little test on `fit_transform` and `transform`methods.

I have a corpus that's a list of strings

```
corpus = ['sentence 1',...]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

Vec = TfidfVectorizer()

X_tfidf1 = Vec.fit_transform(corpus)
X_tfidf2 = Vec.transform(corpus)
```

But :

`np.array_equal(X_tfidf1.todense(),X_tfidf2.todense())` returns False, which does not make sense to me, as Vec is fitted on my corpus, should not the two TFIDF matrix be the same?

Comment: Can you please post where these values are not equal? Probably by comparing values if possible.

Comment: After review, seems to be a rounding error issue, although when using TruncatedSVD, the errors between fit_transform and transform seemed to be greater than just .1%